# Annotations in QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf, qlpreviewcontroller

In offical apps by Apple (for example Mail) is option to make annotations to PDF via this set of buttons:
[image]

I would assume that this is some kind of modified QLPreviewController or similar controller. Unfortunately I have not found any documentation about it. Do exist any official way to implement this to own app?

Thanks!

Comment: Did anybody found solution for this in QLPreviewController ?